# Best means of extracting values from the following string in python?

Tags: python, regex

Assuming I have the following string:

```
thestring = "1) My Favorite Pokemon Charizard *22.00 MP* [Pre-Avatar Mode Cost: 15.75 MP] [Post-Avatar Mode Cost: 6.250 MP]"
```

Some other samples could be:

```
thestring = "1) My Favorite Pokemon Mew *1 MP* [Pre-Avatar Mode Cost: 0.5 MP] [Post-Avatar Mode Cost: 0.5 MP]"

thestring = "1) My Favorite Pokemon Pikachu *6.25 MP* [Pre-Avatar Mode Cost: 5 MP]; [Post-Avatar Mode Cost: 1.25 MP]"
```

(colon for the third case is intentional)

How to best extract the values of "Pre-Casting Cost" and "Post-Avatar Mode Cost"? I hear regex, but also string.find methods, but am not sure what is the best way to accomplish this. Note that there though the "Pre-Avatar Mode Cost" may be 15.75 MP, but could also depending on variety, could also be 15.752 or contain multiple decimal places. Syntax is appreciated.

UPDATE:

I am using Python 2.7. Closest answer is the following:

```
m = re.match('\[Pre-Avatar Mode Cost: (?P<precost>\d(\.\d*){0,1}) MP\] \[Post-Avatar Mode Cost: (?P<postcost>\d(\.\d*){0,1}) MP\]', '1) My Favorite Pokemon Mew *1 MP* [Pre-Avatar Mode Cost: 0.5 MP] [Post-Avatar Mode Cost: 0.5 MP]')
```

Though it appears to not actually match properly resulting in m results in a "Nonetype"due to no matches.

I made a slight change by using the following:

```
m = re.match('(.*)\[.*(?P<precost>\d+(\.\d*){0,1}).*\].*\[.*(?P<postcost>\d+(\.\d*){0,1}).*\]', '1) My Favorite Pokemon Mew *1 MP* [Pre-Avatar Mode Cost: 0.5 MP] [Post-Avatar Mode Cost: 0.5 MP]')
```

Though it appears that precost and postcost are both equal to "5". Any idea what the issue may be with the regular expression?

Comment: Can you share a few more examples of what the strings you are trying to get data from may look like?

Comment: I just updated my answer. The colon is probably throwing off the first match. The second one, the .* needs to be non-greedy so it changes to .*?   I updated my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a regex is the best bet for this:

```
pattern = re.compile(r"\[.*?([0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?).*?\]")
pre, post = [float(x) for x in re.findall(pattern, thestring)]
```

That should work regardless of the number (or lack) of decimal places.

Answer (score 2):

http://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html

Here's the grouping needed:

```
m = re.match('\[Pre-Avatar Mode Cost\: (?P<precost>\d(?:\.\d*)?) MP\] \[Post-Avatar Mode Cost\: (?P<postcost>\d(?:\.\d*)?) MP\]', '1) My Favorite Pokemon Mew *1 MP* [Pre-Avatar Mode Cost: 0.5 MP] [Post-Avatar Mode Cost: 0.5 MP]')
```

here's how you access your groups:

```
m.group('precost')
m.group('postcost')
```

If you don't care about the contents of the strings and know that the values are in 2 square brackets, you can just:

```
m = re.match('\[.*?(?P<precost>\d+(?:\.\d*)?).*?\].*?\[.*?(?P<postcost>\d+(?:\.\d*)?).*\]', 'your long string')
m.group('precost')
m.group('postcost')
```

Comment: Tried using the above and got a "sre_constants.error: bad character in group name" and what appears to be an invalid expression (on the line right after "Here's the grouping needed"

Comment: stuck an = sign behind the P name designator by accident.. confirm the syntax against the page I linked to.

Comment: Feels close... That seemed to have fixed that error, but when attempting to print out the group with m.group("precost") there is a AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

Comment: try single quotes.. I also fixed up one error.. the decimal point was not escaped.

Comment: Tried replacing all double quotes with single quotes, but appear to get the same error:         m = re.match('\[Pre-Avatar Mode Cost: (?P<precost>\d(\.\d*){0,1}) MP\] \[Post-Avatar Mode Cost: (?P<postcost>\d(\.\d*){0,1}) MP\]', '1) My Favorite Pokemon Mew *1 MP* [Pre-Avatar Mode Cost: 0.5 MP] [Post-Avatar Mode Cost: 0.5 MP]')

Comment: yes of course. This came from the fact that the initial question implied there could be 2.40.60 type of a pattern. Changed it now.

Comment: added one more non-greedy marker.. try using groups. it's way easier to read when you come back to your code.

Answer (score 0):

This may make too many assumptions about what there is *not* in the texts you are searching for, but will be certainly shorter and possibly faster:

```
re.findall('\[Pre[^:]+:\s+(?P<precost>\S+)[^[]+\[Post[^:]+:\s+(?P<postcost>\S+)', 
    thestring)
[('5', '1.25')]
```

These assumptions may not be correct:

- there's always a space after the cost and before "PM".
- the colon inside square brackets happens only once, and it is always placed after "cost".
- there aren't any other groups inside brackets which would start with "Pre" or "Post" sequence.

Answer (score -1):

Definitely RegEx, because it is so precise. I don't see the "Pre-Casting Cost" section that you are talking about. Perhaps you meant "Pre-Avatar Mode"?

But for the Post-Avatar Mode Cost you have to think through how consistent certain text is. If you know that "Post-Avatar Mode Cost: " is always the consistent delimiter, you can do a simple match.

Assuming you want the float value there, you can do something like:

```
import re
post_avatar_cost = re.match("\[Post-Avatar Mode Cost: (?P<PostCost>[0-9]*\.[0-9]*) MP\]")
post_avatar_cost = post_avatar_cost.group('PostCost')
```

And that would give you just the float (as a string). I'm making a lot of assumptions here for example, and I'm writing something quick to give you an idea. But you can toss that in a loop to find all of those values.

This page will be your best friend: http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html

Comment: you don't need non-greedy designators on the actual cost matching. You can add an inner group for the cost, name it and access the group by that name. No need to resort to sub if you're using regex groups properly.

Comment: Appreciate the advice Adam, that's helpful. I like what you did with yours.